# Python PyQt6 QWidget con ScrollArea

Tags: python, pyqt6

tengo un MainWindow con un grupo de widgets, todos en un QStackedLayout.

Dentro de uno de los Widgets, agregué otro widget, quisiera ponerle a este último un QScrollArea, he intentado diferentes cosas pero no lo logro, lo que tengo es esto:

```
# widget principal que está en el QStackedLayout()
widget = QWidget

# Es el layout del widget principal
vbox = QVBoxLayout()

scroll = QScrollArea()
scroll.setWidget(self.w7)
```

Lo que necesito es que ese "sub" widget tenga un tamaño establecido y se pueda hacer scroll, porque sí se ingresan bastantes datos.

Comment: A pesar de haber usado pyside2 (que usa una versión anterior de qt), creo que no va a haber ningún problema. Escribí un código usando un QLabel de subwidget y no me sucede ningún error. Prodrías agregar un código el cual, pegado en mi editor y ejecutado, de el mismo error por favor? esto para entender mejor el contexto y hacer pruebas.